# how to uncomment code in matlab online script

Tags: matlab

I just ran into this weird issue, that I cannot uncomment my code in a script file online on matlab.

I can do command + '/' to comment my code, but I cannot do the inverse to uncomment it.
I've tried to use command + T, which opens a new tab, command + / again, which keeps commenting my code, and command + R, which restarts the kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uncomment command conflicts with the open new tab command. The latter is prioritised because MATLAB online runs in the browser.

Moreover, shortcut customisation [is not available in MATLAB Online](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/use-keyboard-shortcuts-to-navigate-matlab.html).

So your only chance to make the uncomment shortcut work is to change the open new tab shortcut in the browser.

EDIT: For an alternative solution that does not involve shortcuts, please check the answer by Harshal.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue but then I selected the multiple lines of code and used mouse (right click) to comment and uncomment the selected code.